# ContentUri's format for id as string

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Content uri generally is in this format

```
content://provider/product/1
```

Can a contenturi be made to accept such uri

```
content://provider/product/p1
```

can id be string?
I am trying to use `ContentUris.withAppendedId(contentUri,id)`. this id seems to be type long.

Comment: I used Uri.withAppendedPath(uri,'p1') to create the uri. Would that be problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely in the way you've defined your UriMatcher.

You are probably using a pattern matcher for that uri and table which ends with a "#", so it's looking for a number.

Just add another matcher pattern exactly like what you already have but change the "#" to a "*" so it will also match on a string.

Here's an example I used where my table had both and _id column and a device_id column. The device_id column had a NOT NULL and UNIQUE constraint and held UUIDs. Either of the the two columns could be used as row identifiers.

sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, DevicesTable.TABLE_NAME + "/#", DEVICE);
sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, DevicesTable.TABLE_NAME + "/*", DEVICE);

With this in place you can call either Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, _id); or URi.withAppendedPath(uri, uuid); and the matcher would find the right table.

Just be sure to adjust your ContentProvider to query the right fields for either case.